# Use of Cap here

Tags: capacitor, audio

I am looking at reference schematic for Mic Preamplifier. I have posted a part of schematic here:[image: Schematic]

So the net VDD_MIC is used to provide a DC offset to signals SPKR_MIC_P, SPKR_MIC_N.
I wonder whats the use of C483 here? For DC it's open however for AC R494 and C483 will act as a high pass filter, this will increase the coupling between the SPKR_MIC_P and SPKR_MIC_N.

What's the rationale behind doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it is just decoupling the rails from the bias. Basically forming two sub-rails a 1K drop from VDD_Mic and Ground.

If you redraw it this way it is a tad clearer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJp8hN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>